# Prove By Mathematical Induction (factorial-to-the-fourth vs power of two)

Tags: logic, induction

Prove $(n!)^{4}\le2^{n(n+1)}$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3,...$

Base Step: $(0!)^{4} = 1 \le 2^{0(0+1)} = 1$

IH: Assume that $(k!)^{4} \le 2^{k(k+1)}$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$.

Induction Step: Show $(k+1!)^{4} \le 2^{k+1((k+1)+1)}$

Proof: $(k+1!)^{4} = (k+1)^{4}*(k!)^{4}$ By the definition of factorial. 
$$\begin{align*}
(k+1)^{4}*(k!)^{4} &\le (k+1)^{4}*2^{k(k+1)}\\
&\le (k+1)^{4}*2^{(k+1)((k+1)+1)}
\end{align*}$$ 
by the IH.

That is as far as I have been able to get at this point...Please Help! Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your solution has the right structure, and is a good start.  You only need to prove that $(k+1)^42^{k^2+k}\le 2^{(k+1)(k+2)}=2^{k^2+3k+2}$, i.e. $(k+1)^4\le 2^{2k+2}$.

Answer (score 1):

That last $\leq$ is leading you astray. Here's the last correct step: $$((k+1)!)^4 = (k+1)^4 (k!)^4 \leq (k+1)^4 2^{k(k+1)}.$$ Your *goal* is to show that $$(k+1)^4 2^{k(k+1)} \leq 2^{(k+1)((k+1)+1)}.$$ Try dividing both sides by a common factor andd see what's left...

Comment: I didvided both sides by 2^{k(k+1)} and get that (k+1)^{4} is less than or equal to 2^{2k+2} = 2^{2(k+1)} which almosts resembles what I set out to prove except for the fact that I need to show (k+1!)^{4} is less than or equal to 2^{k(k+1)}

Comment: Yes, but I dare say $(k+1)^4\leq 2^{2(k+1)}$ will be far easier to prove. You may very well need to do so by induction.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing well up to $(k+1)^4*(k!)^4 \le (k+1)^4*2^{k(k+1)}$  That is the proper use of the induction hypothesis.  Now you need to argue $(k+1)^4 \le \frac {2^{(k+1)(k+2)}}{2^{k(k+1)}}=2^{(k+1)(k+2)-k(k+1)}=2^{2(k+1)}$

Comment: I didvided both sides by 2^{k(k+1)} and get that (k+1)^{4} is less than or equal to 2^{2k+2} = 2^{2(k+1)} which almosts resembles what I set out to prove except for the fact that I need to show (k+1!)^{4} is less than or equal to 2^{k(k+1)}

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do a secondary proof by induction to prove this. What you want to show is the following (I hope my LaTeX renders properly): $((n+1)!)^4 \leq 2^{(n+1)(n+2)}$. We know from the inductive hypothesis that $(n!)^4 \le 2^{n(n+1)}$. Multiplying on both sides by $(n+1)^4$, we have $((n+1)!)^4 \leq (n+1)^4 2^{n(n+1)}$. For the proof to be complete, you only need to show that $(n+1)^4 2^{n(n+1)} \leq 2^{(n+1)(n+2)}$. This can be done easily with a secondary proof by induction after doing a little bit of rearranging of terms in the inequality.